# How to get file size in KB and MB in android

Tags: java, android

I want code that i can get file size and change it to KB and MB

```
562 KB  =  562 KB
1024 KB =    1 MB
2152 KB = 2.15 MB
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: thanks for giving me link!
sorry im newbie thats why im confused!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here it's:

```
public String size(int size){
    String hrSize = "";
    double m = size/1024.0;
    DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    if (m > 1) {
        hrSize = dec.format(m).concat(" MB");
    } else {
        hrSize = dec.format(size).concat(" KB");
    }
    return hrSize;
}
```

SOURCE: [Converting KB to MB, GB, TB dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539871/converting-kb-to-mb-gb-tb-dynamicaly)

Comment: On Android, there is a way to use [Formatter.formatFileSize(context: Context?, sizeBytes: Long): String!](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/text/format/Formatter#formatfilesize)