# How to list the FTP files of a directory only having txt extension using java?

Tags: java, file, ftp

I have a number of FTP files having .txt extension in my ftp server's Directory.

Now I want to list the files having .txt extension using java.

I have tried `.endsWith(.txt)`, but it shows compile time error as :

> Cannot cast from FTPFile to String

Can any one help me to achieve this?

Below are my codes:

```
package com;

import java.io.File;
import edu.vt.middleware.crypt.io.TeePrintStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ConnectException;
//import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;  
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;  
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPConnectMode;
import com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPException;
import com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPTransferType;
import com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.Protocol;
import com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.SecureFileTransferClient;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import edu.vt.middleware.crypt.io.TeePrintStream;

public class getFilesFTP
{
public static File dir=new File("D:/log_FTPCHECK");
 public static String logname="output.txt";
 public static File logfile=new File(dir,logname);
 public static StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();

public static void main(String args[]) throws 
SecurityException,FTPException, IOException,ConnectException, 
AddressException, MessagingException

{

sb.append("**********************************************************
************************************************************************
************************");
    sb.append("<p align=center><B><U>SCOPUS FILE UPLOAD CHECK AUTO 
GENERATED LOG REPORT</U></B></p>");
   sb.append("***************************************************
*******************************************************
************************************************"); 
String host="sftp-opsbank2.elsevier.com";
String username="tho-e";
String password="Tho5540b2E";
int count=0;
File Filename;;
Date FileDate;
String invalidfilename=".";
String filetype="";
//DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/year");
//String date1="";
String Lastmodifieddata="";
Date todayDate;





     try{

         SimpleDateFormat dateformat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
         String timeStamp = 
dateformat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        // System.out.println("I am executed2");
            System.out.println("Todays Date :"+timeStamp );
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            sb.append("Todays Date :"+timeStamp );  
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
           // System.out.println("I am executed2");
            SecureFileTransferClient client=new 
SecureFileTransferClient();
client.getAdvancedFTPSettings().setConnectMode(FTPConnectMode.PASV);

            client.setRemoteHost(host);
            client.setUserName(username);
            client.setPassword(password);
            client.setProtocol(Protocol.SFTP);
            client.setRemotePort(22);

            client.setContentType(FTPTransferType.BINARY);
             sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
             System.out.println("connecting to sftp");
             sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            sb.append("connecting to sftp");
             sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            client.connect();
            System.out.println("SFTP Connection established  
 successfully...");
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            sb.append("SFTP Connection established successfully...");
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());

            String path1="/sftp/content-providers/tho-e/data/incoming   
/scopusbk";
            com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPFile[] directroy =    
client.directoryList(path1);
            System.out.println("Total Number of Files Found 
:"+directroy.length);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            sb.append("Total Number of Files Found :"+directroy.length);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            int x=0;

            for (int i = 0; i < directroy.length; i++) 
            {
                //System.out.println("entered in for loop");
                Filename= new File(directroy[i].getName());
                FileDate=(Date) directroy[i].lastModified();
                //Filetype=getFileExtension(Filename);
            //  System.out.println("Name:"+Filename);

Lastmodifieddata=dateformat.format(directroy[i].lastModified());

                if(timeStamp.equalsIgnoreCase(Lastmodifieddata)  )


                {   
                    if (((String) directroy[i]).endsWith("txt"))
                    {

                System.out.println("File Name:"+Filename +" ||Last    
 Modified : "+Lastmodifieddata);
                 sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                sb.append("File Name:"+Filename +" ||Last Modified : 
"+Lastmodifieddata);
                 sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                //System.out.println();


                // String path1="/sftp/suppliers/thomdi/signals
/ContentCAR";
                // com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPFile[] directroy = 
client.directoryList(path1);
                count++;
                    }
            }

                else
                {
                    //System.out.println("No todays files");
                }
     }
            System.out.println("Total Number of file :"+count);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            sb.append("Total Number of file :"+count);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
          //  PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new 
FileOutputStream("D:/output.txt"));
          //  System.setOut(out);
            if(!logfile.exists())
            {
            logfile.createNewFile();
            }

            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(logfile,sb.toString());
            FTPMailer.sendmailFTP();

            count=0;


     }
     catch(SecurityException se)
     {
         System.out.println("This belongs to security exception");
         sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
         sb.append("This belongs to security exception");
         sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
         se.printStackTrace();

     }
     catch(ConnectException ce)
     {
         System.out.println("Unable to Reach FTP Server..");
         System.out.println("Check the Internet Connectivity");
         sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
         sb.append("Unable to Reach FTP Server..");
         sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
         sb.append("Check the Internet Connectivity");
         sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
     }

}
}
```

Comment: `if ((directroy[i]).getName().endsWith("txt"))`.

Comment: Here `directroy` is an array of `FTPFile` type.

Comment: Thank you satya.It works fine.

Comment: you are so fast....Great..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
if (((String) directroy[i]).endsWith("txt"))
```

to

```
if ((directroy[i]).getName().endsWith("txt"))
```

**Edit:**

```
long size = directroy[i].getSize();//get file size
```

> long getSize(): gets file size in bytes.

Comment: can you please suggest how to get the FTP file size for the same above asked?
I have tried filesize=directroy[i].getName().getBytes();

Comment: but it gives result as :  Size in bytes : [B@14340bb

Comment: but i need as 5kb,10kb like that instead of [B@14340bb

Comment: `getBytes()` returns bytes of string results from `directroy[i].getName()`. But not file size.

Comment: But it throws compile time error "The method getSize() is undefined for the type FTPFile"

Comment: @IlavarasanJayaraman [Read this doc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPFile.html#getSize())

Comment: Thank you.it works with long size = directroy[i].size();

Comment: @IlavarasanJayaraman [Converting bytes to kb, mb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539871/converting-kb-to-mb-gb-tb-dynamicaly)