# Get current size of photo on screen

Tags: flutter

I have to know  current size of photo on screen (as example, original photo size is 1200*700, but then I put it on some screen of devise with total width 480, and picture(photo) tightened and its size start to be 480 * [*some-changed-height*]).

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665955/how-do-i-determine-the-width-and-height-of-an-image-in-flutter) topic, but it doesn't help, the case is a bit different, as me understand.  Are here more ways? Thx!

Comment: what is this topic.... it's not a link

Comment: does this answer help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/64571102/13497264

Answer (score 0):

I found solution [there](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-get-widget-size-and-position)

I took a size of widget that contained photo by key and it helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).